# table R - create a table by selecting the first value and adding the others with a formula

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I want to create a new table on R after finding my growth rates of a value.

My formula to obtain is: Z <- Variable at T-1 * (1+ rate) with the first value of Z, the firt value of "variable"

simplified example below:

```
variable <- c(1,2,3,4)
rate <- c(1,0.5,0.333)
z <-
data.frame(variable,rate,z)
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
variable  rate z
1        1   0  1
2        2 1.000 2
3        3 0.500 3
4        4 0.333 4
```

(this is for a table with more financial values that has been simplified to make it easier to understand your answer.)

Thank you in advance

```
variable  rate z
1        1 0.000 1
2        2 1.000 2
3        3 0.500 3
4        4 0.333 4
```

Comment: How is `z == 2` in the second row? If `1 * (1+2) = 3`?

Comment: Sorry, rate <- (0,1,0.5,0.33), thank you for seeing the error

Answer (score 0):

Get the `lag` of the 'variable' and do the calculation

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(z = round(lag(variable, default = first(variable)) * (1 + rate)))
```

-output

```
df1
   variable  rate z
1        1 0.000 1
2        2 1.000 2
3        3 0.500 3
4        4 0.333 4
```